# Unable To Execute Appium Execution With Page Factory Model Implementaion

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, page-factory

.
      I am using Appium 1.9.1 Version
        MacBook Air 10.13.6
        Java client 6.1.0
        Latest Seleniumjar file I am trying to implementing page factory model with appium selenium ( java) but i am not able to perform any action. Eveytime application launched sucessfully in android device but after launching appication it is throwing error .

*----------

```
    I am adding all class file 

    Launch application Code 
    public class AppLaunch {

        public static WebDriver mdriver;

        public WebDriver launchApplication() {

            //-Picking application apk file inside project folder
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");        
            File appPath = new File(rootPath+"/apkfile/app-beta-debug.apk");
            System.out.println("Print app path " +appPath);

            //-Setting capabilities for android application process
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
            cap.setCapability("appium-version", "1.9.1");
            cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1");
            cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Moto X Play");
            cap.setCapability("app", "/Users/daffolapmac-73/eclipse-workspace/Wapanda_Driver_Automation/apkfile/app-beta-debug.apk" );
            cap.setCapability("appPackage", "co.wapanda.android.beta");
            cap.setCapability("appActivity","co.wapanda.android.screens.splash.view.SplashActivity");

            //-Setting server host and port with default values
            String host = "127.0.0.1";
            String port = "4723";

            try {
                mdriver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), cap);
                mdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return mdriver;

        }

        public static WebDriver getWebDriverInstance() {
            return mdriver;
        }


    }



    ------------------------------
    Now I am adding Signup page 



    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
    import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

    public class DriverSignUpPages {

         AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

         public DriverSignUpPages(WebDriver driver){
          this.driver = (AndroidDriver<MobileElement>)driver;
          PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
         }

        @AndroidFindBy(className = "UIAKeyboard")
         AndroidElement keyboard;

        @AndroidFindBy(id = "usernameTextField")
        public static AndroidElement username;

    }



    ------------------------------

    Now I am adding Test Case Execution file 



import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.wapanda.pages.DriverSignUpPages;
import com.wapanda.setup.AppLaunch;
public class ValidateDriverProcess {


    AppLaunch applaunch;
    DriverSignUpPages dprocess;
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void launchApplication( ) {
        applaunch = new AppLaunch();
        applaunch.launchApplication();
    }

     @Test
    public void validateDriverSignupProcess() {
        try {
         DriverSignUpPages dprocess = new DriverSignUpPages(driver);
        System.out.println("Inside test case ");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeApplication() {
        driver.close();
    }


}
When i am launching application with POM page factory i am getting following error 
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod closeApplication
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.wapanda.tests.ValidateDriverProcess.closeApplication(ValidateDriverProcess.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
FAILED: validateDriverSignupProcess
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:52)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.utils.ProxyFactory.getEnhancedProxy(ProxyFactory.java:33)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.proxyForAnElement(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.access$0(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:215)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator$1.proxyForLocator(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
    at com.wapanda.pages.DriverSignUpPages.<init>(DriverSignUpPages.java:17)
    at com.wapanda.tests.ValidateDriverProcess.validateDriverSignupProcess(ValidateDriverProcess.java:28)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.getClassVisitor(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:30)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:24)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
    ... 43 more
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================*
```

Comment: You're not assigning your driver that is returned from your class.  `applaunch.launchApplication();` should be `driver = applaunch.launchApplication();`

Comment: @BillHileman Now i am getting.I want to close application  FAILED CONFIGURATION: @ AfterMethod closeApplication
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:32:14.902Z'
System info: host: 'Daffolapmac-73s-MacBook-Air.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:73:1418:5911:1e15%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '10.0.2'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {app: /Users/daffolapmac-